# concatenate every two characters of string

Tags: python, string, slice

I'm new to Python. I have a string:

```
food = "popcorns"
beverage = "water"
```

How do I create a new string that concatenates every two characters and skips the third? Like this:

PO-CO-NS and
WA-ER

so that the new string becomes

```
new_food = pocons
new_beverage = waer
```

I'm trying to build a new 100 character string from an infinite string using this kind of concatenation. Here's what I have so far:

```
infinite_string
for i in range(0, 32):
    new_string += infinite_string[i: i + 1: 3]
```

I know this isn't right. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no such thing as an infinite string.

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(inputstring, 1) if i % 3])
```

Demo:

```
>>> food = "popcorns"
>>> beverage = "water"
>>> ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(food, 1) if i % 3])
'pocons'
>>> ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(beverage, 1) if i % 3])
'waer'
```

Another method is to *delete* every third character after first creating a list:

```
characters = list(inputstring)
del characters[2::3]
result = ''.join(characters)
```

Demo:

```
>>> characters = list(food)
>>> del characters[2::3]
>>> ''.join(characters)
'pocons'
```

Comment: @Aprillion: strings *cannot be infinite* however.

Comment: I am sure one can come up with a string-like object that is infinite, `infinite_string` is not necessarily a built-in

Comment: when I say infinite string, I don't mean an infinite string. I mean like a 1000 character string. I need something robust enough to handle a large string.

Comment: @cooldood3490: 1000 is not large. This'll handle your string.

Answer (score 5):

Using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(..).', r'\1', "popcorns")
'pocons'
>>> re.sub('(..).', r'\1', "water")
'waer'
```

Comment: missing instruction to limit to 100 characters, if the input is infinite string...

Comment: To limit the resulting string 100 characters long, `re.sub('(..).', r'\1', big_string[:150])` would be enough. (150 comes from 100 * 3 / 2)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> food = "popcorns"
>>> ''.join(''.join(i) for i in zip(food[0::3], food[1::3]))
'pocons'
```

Answer (score 1):

A readable and efficient version:

```
''.join([input_str[i] for i in xrange(input_len) if i % 3 != 2])
```

I tested the performance of the four answers in ipython, here are the results:

```
import re
input_str = 'popcons'
input_len = len(input_str)

%timeit -n 10000 ''.join([input_str[i] for i in xrange(input_len) if i % 3 != 2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(input_str, 1) if i % 3])
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 re.sub('(..).', r'\1', input_str)
10000 loops, best of 3: 8.29 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 ''.join(''.join(i) for i in zip(input_str[0::3], input_str[1::3]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate new string with x characters, you can use `range` as you tried, but you need to multiply the string indexes by number of characters retrieved+skipped in each step:

```
s = infinite_string
characters_total = 100
include_characters = 2
skip_characters = 1
step = include_characters + skip_characters
new_s  = ''.join(
    s[i * step : i * step + include_characters]
    for i in range(characters_total / include_characters))
```